# Increase font size of bootstrap tooltip popover for bootstrap4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have subject lines with entire descriptions as popover text. There is a lot of text and the default size is too small. I checked out the earlier question [How can I customize the text font size of my bootstrap tooltip popover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52336559/how-can-i-customize-the-text-font-size-of-my-bootstrap-tooltip-popover/52336820) but it does not seem to work - probably because this was for the earlier versions of bootstrap. It would even be nice if I can get a popover that is well formatted with header, body, etc. but I will be happy with at least a bigger font size for now.

Comment: Can you post your active pop-over html so we can see how to target elements? Code or screenshots of DOM would be useful.

Comment: `<tr class="table-danger" data-key="377">
<td>1</td>
<td title="The survey is typically a single page document showing the a property&#039;s boundary lines and legal description among other restrictions or easements included in the property. This is usually provided by the buyer (or builder) during the purchase of the home." data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-container="body">Upload Survey of the house</td>
</tr>
`